# How to include the maximum capacity of the local database into the capacity of the app package?

Tags: windows, sqlite, installation, desktop-application

I'm working on developing Windows desktop app using Qt framework and SQLite.
The installation file for my distributed app is created using [Microsoft Visual Studio's Setup Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-deploying-a-visual-cpp-application-by-using-a-setup-project?view=msvc-170).

The application uses SQLite as local db, and the database file is stored in Windows AppData path.
For example, `C:/Users/<name>/AppData/Roaming/<ProductName>/db.sqlite`

I don't want the size of the database file to increase infinitely, so limited `max_page_count`.
Now I can presume that the maximum database file size is `page_size * max_page_count` bytes.

Let's assume the size of my app package is 5GB and the size of maximum database file is 10GB.
**If there is only 8GB left in the C drive of the user's PC, my app will be installed successfully. However, when the size of database file increases dynamically, the lack of drive space will be a problem.**

How to prevent above situation?

I think the best solution is to make final required capacity of the app to be the sum of the maximum size of the database file and my app's package. To do this, the database file size should be static(as its maximum size), so I might have to do fill the initial database with empty pages. Also SQLite's `VACUUM` command cannot be used anymore. It seems not good in terms of performance.

Any advice would be appreciated.